# How to create iphone webapp on windows? (I can use my friend's mac for finishing)

Tags: iphone, windows, web-applications

I know a lot of similar questions have been asked, but my case is a little different.

I have a windows machine on which I want to do the development. I can borrow my friend's mac for signing/publishing to store or other things.

Is it possible to do this? Can I create a "Dynamic Web App Project" in eclipse, do the coding and finally use a MAC to finish it?  My app is 100% offline app.

Where can I find the directory structure for the HTML/CSS files?

How can I achieve the iphone look and feel of buttons and other UI?

I know that many people have done this but I cant find any tutorial. Please point me to one if you know about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this would be a great job for phone gap.

http://phonegap.com/

They provide wrapping software to make your web application run natively on the phone.

Comment: phone gap says --Requirements:  Intel-based computer with Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6) . So I guess, I cannot develop on windows :(

Comment: That is only for deploying. The application is just HTML,CSS,JS which from what I recall you CAN do that on Windows.

Comment: Wow. You clearly stated you could find a mac to deploy to. Built your app in windows then bring the code over to your friends mac for deploying.

Comment: Jake , thanks for your help .  So, how do I develop in windows ? Like any "dynamic web app " in eclipse ? Please answer this one last question . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should look at [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com) for the coding.

For getting your buttons, backgrounds, icons and such to look and feel more like native iOS apps, take a look at this [list of graphics for iOS](http://webdesignledger.com/freebies/11-ui-kits-for-iphone-and-ipad-development). Most are free. There are .zip files with pre cut images, and a number of .psd files for you to choose from. If you are not using xCode or Titanium to build the apps, these are a nice way of getting that native look and feel.

Comment: phone gap says --Requirements:  Intel-based computer with Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6) . So I guess, I cannot develop on windows :(